# Paging in Umbraco

Tags: pagination, umbraco

I'm working in my Umbraco based website, and I have a page that contains objects arranged in a grid, and the amount of objects is getting bigger so I'll need to create pagination to this page. How can I create the pagination?
I'm new with Umbraco and website development, sorry of this is a stupid question.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here: [link on umbraco forum pagination](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/66846-pagination-on-site)

Comment: Using System.Linq, you can do a .Skip(x) and .Take(x) on your array. You can add current page number to querystring and work out how many to skip using that and a preset items per page variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://github.com/Shazwazza/Articulate/blob/master/src/Articulate.Web/App_Plugins/Articulate/Themes/Edictum/Views/Partials/Pager.cshtml)

```
@if (Model.HasNext || Model.HasPrevious) {
    <nav class="pagination" role="pagination">
        @if (Model.HasPrevious) {
            <a class="newer-posts" href="@Model.PreviousUrl">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Newer
            </a>
        }
        <span class="page-number">Page @(Model.CurrentPageIndex + 1) of 
        @Model.TotalPages</span>
        @if (Model.HasNext) {
            <a class="older-posts" href="@Model.NextUrl">
                Older <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
            </a>
        }
    </nav>
}
```

This code is from Articulate Blog engine (Umbraco plugin). You must create a custom `Pager` model.